# GAE Datastore - Single composite index for all sort operations

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I am using GAE(java) and objectify to query the datastore. I have a query where the entities will be filtered based on three different properties. Since they are indexed, it works fine. But i need to sort the results based on another property. So i added composite index something like this

entity kind ->

-- fiterProperty1 asc

-- fiterProperty2 asc

-- fiterProperty3 asc

-- sortingProperting desc

It works fine as well. But i have more than six other properties with which query can be sorted. (One sorting at a time for query. not all six at a time). So the questions are :

1. I could add all six combinations of composite index. Will that increase the index count (from what i have read so far 200 is the limit for max indexes)
2. Can i add all the sorting options in a single composite index like this

entity kind ->

-- fiterProperty1 asc

-- fiterProperty2 asc

-- fiterProperty3 asc

-- sortingProperting1 desc

-- sortingProperting2 desc

-- sortingProperting3 desc

-- sortingProperting4 desc

-- sortingProperting5 desc

-- sortingProperting6 desc

will this work? I want to reduce the write counts and the size of the datastore.

I need to re-save all the entities again to test whether the query works. So kindly help me to avoid some overhead.

**What I have got so far reading other stackoverflow posts :**
Query all the entities and sort it in code. This wont work for me because i have more than 10000 entities for single kind. I dont think this will be a feasible solution either.

Comment: The default way would be to run all required queries on the devserver and see what the autogenerated index file contains afterwards. regarding 1) Each index increases the index count, so yes. 2) that should work. In general: Such complex composite indexes often stem from overly complex or unoptimized entity models. Depending on how often you need to do such a query you might want to do some filtering/sorting in memory and cache the result in a result table for later usage.

Comment: Thanks for the help.